# C#: How does the static object.Equals check for equality?

Tags: c#, object, static, equals

Say you have two different classes where each have their own implementation of Equals; which one is used? What if only one of them have one? Or none of them? Are any of the following lines equivalent?

```
object .Equals( first, second )
first .Equals( second )
second .Equals( first )
```

I'm guessing that the first two might be equivalent, but I don't really have a clue.

What does it really do?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Basically it does three things:

- Check for reference equality (return true if so)
- Check for reference nullity (return false if either value is null; by now the null == null case has been handled)
- Check for value equality with `first.Equals(second)`

The ordering *shouldn't* matter if both values have well-behaved equality implementations, as equality should be implemented such that `x.Equals(y)` implies `y.Equals(x)`. However, the offline documentation I've got installed does state that first.Equals(second) (or objA.equals(objB) to use the real parameter naming) is specified. The [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) doesn't mention this, interestingly enough.

Just to make all of this concrete, the implementation could look like this:

```
public static bool Equals(object x, object y)
{
    if (x == y) // Reference equality only; overloaded operators are ignored
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (x == null || y == null) // Again, reference checks
    {
        return false;
    }
    return x.Equals(y); // Safe as we know x != null.
}
```

Comment: It must be highlighted that the main difference between the static `Object.Equals` and the virtual `first.Equals(second)` is that the latter **will fail** if `first` is a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

By default, object equivalency is determined by the object's address in memory.  If both instances have the same memory address, they are equal.

However, this can be overloaded within the object so that developers can compare two objects that *arn't* in the same memory location and still be considered equal.  For example, if you had a Data Access Layer where each object had its data record's ID from the database, you could have object equality compared based on the ID.

You can [overload operators](http://ikriv.com:8765/en/prog/info/dotnet/ObjectEquality.html) to produce this functionality.

Comment: You can't override operators in C#. You can *overload* operators, or *override* the Equals method.