# Why C# Object class has two equals method

Tags: java, c#, oop

As a newbie in *C#* want to know why `Object` class of C# have *two* `Equals` method with below signature.

```
public virtual bool Equals(object obj);
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB);
```

While in *Java* there is only *one* `equals` method.

Comment: @MickyD I read documentation as well but didn't get much difference between these two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451454/c-how-does-the-static-object-equals-check-for-equality - this is not exact duplicate, but is should give you right direction.

Comment: Because you might want to compare two values that can be null. You get an exception for `A.Equals(B)` where A is null. So you can use `object.Equals(A, B)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First

```
public virtual bool Equals(object obj);
```

is a standard, typical etc. method to compare objects: if `this` equals to `obj` similar to Java's

Second

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB);
```

is a kind of sugar for you not to compare `objA` with `null` each time you want to compare `objA`, `objB` instances

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,f2a579c50b414717

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
{
    if (objA==objB) {
        return true;
    }
    if (objA==null || objB==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

Java *does have* a similar method:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)

```
// Please, note Objects instead of Object
Objects.equals(Object a, Object b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one compares the current instance with the one provided in the parameter. The later compares A with B as its a static method

Answer (score 0):

The first "Equals" method compares the caller object with the arguments....
CallerObject.Equals(targetComparerObject),
Moreover, we can also define a custom override for this method in child  classes.

The second equals method compares two arguments with each other... :) we cannot override it.

Moreover, in Java the equals methods only compares the memory location. that means when we say
obj1.equals(obj2), by default it compares only references, whether they are pointing to same location or not...
If we want any custom comparison, we need to override it in JAVA..

Comment: When you say you can't override the second method... not directly, but it calls the first after performing null comparisons, so it's not like you can't affect its behaviour...

Comment: Correct, my statement is true in case when we want to change the behavior before null checks..

Comment: But it's misleading in every other case - and as the contract of `Equals` is that it's meant to be symmetric, it's very rare that you *do* want to change how nullity is handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual bool Equals(object obj)
```

This is a **object method** available in every class object. You use this method to compare current object with the one you passed as a argument.

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
```

This is a **class method** available in the  `Object` class which is a top most parent class of all the other classes in C# which means every class in C# is derived from base class `Object`. It is available as static requiring you to pass two objects as the arguments to get compared.

For more information and examples, you can refer to the documentation.

```
Object.Equals(obj1, obj2)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx

```
obj1.Equals(obj2)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't see any difference between C# and Java in this case. Both do object comparison. It's just about language implementation. C# implemented it in two ways and Java defined it in its own way having it as a object method rather than going for a static one like C#.